# multiple matching crates for `time` but there're no versions specified

Tags: rust

I've imported a create `time` and I'm using another crate which also uses (imports) `time`, because of this I have an error:

```
/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/my_project/src/lib.rs:2:1: 2:19 error: multiple matching crates for `time`
/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/my_project/src/lib.rs:2 extern crate time;
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidates:
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libtime-4e7c5e5c.dylib
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libtime-4e7c5e5c.rlib
note: crate name: time
note: path: /Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/my_project/target/deps/libtime-8fdb58a7632ec071.rlib
note: crate name: time
/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/my_project/src/lib.rs:2:1: 2:19 error: can't find crate for `time`
/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/my_project/src/lib.rs:2 extern crate time;
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

If I comment out `time` I'll have an error as well that `time` isn't found. The error above doesn't even explain what the versions of `time` are. Which one should I delete from the disk?

Comment: Are you using cargo ?

Answer (score 4):

The crate time has recently been move to an external repository, but you currently still have the old crate bundled with rustc, as it is currently kept as deprecated.

Thus you have two crates "libtime", and rustc doesn't know which take.

As you're using cargo, the fix is simple: add libtime in your dependencies by putting this in your `Cargo.toml`, cargo will tell rusctc which libtime it should use.

```
[dependencies.time]
git = "https://github.com/rust-lang/time"
```

Comment: should I delete some from my hard drive? I'm using the newest version of Rust, how is it possible?

Comment: The old libtime is still published with rustc. This way, users still using it should receive a deprecation warning rather than a cryptic error that the library is missing. However in situations like yours it turned out not so great.

Comment: which one should I delete?

Comment: If you use cargo properly you should not need to delete any. If you really want to delete one, it should be the one bundled with rustc (the one in `/usr/local/lib/...` in your case)

Comment: how may I not use cargo properly?

Comment: I have found in my case the only solution was to delete the installed rust library /usr/local/lib64/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libtime-4e7c5e5c.so and /usr/local/lib64/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libtime-4e7c5e5c.rlib due to dependency usage of specific time crates that collided with my ability to put the time crate in my Cargo.toml.  Just FYI.